# Trying to change kali username, user is currently used by process

Tags: kali-linux, users, vmware, usermod

On a VMware Workstation Player VM, I have been trying to change my default user account name "kali". The command I tried was `usermod -l newname kali`. But it gives me the error `usermod: user kali is currently used by process 823`. Before anyone asks, yes I did this while logged in as root.

Comment: so, what is your question?

Comment: How do I correctly change my username and circumvent the error

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that `kali` is still logged in.

If you are logged into your desktop environment (e.g. gnome/kde) as `kali`, then that user will own some of the graphical processes.  `kali` must not be logged into any graphical sessions.

If you are in a TTY, then I'm guessing you have a situation like this:

```
kali ~ $ su root
root ~ # usermod -l newname kali
usermod: user kali is currently used by process 823
```

In this case, you are logged in as `kali`, then `kali` owns a terminal which is logged in by `root`.  If you `ps -ef --forest` this situation it would look something like this:

```
kali      290538       1 ?       /bin/sh -c i3-sensible-terminal
kali      290539  290538 ?        \_ x-terminal-emulator
kali      290542  290539 pts/1        \_ /bin/bash
root      290697  290542 pts/1            \_ su root
root      290698  290697 pts/1                \_ bash
root      290711  290698 pts/1                    \_ ps -ef --forest
```

You can see that you are `root`, but you can also see that `kali` is still active down the stack and owns the shell that root is running.

---

If you are relying on a desktop environment to access your terminal, then here are two options:

1. Create `newname`, move everything, then delete `kali`
2. Create `tempuser`, logout as `kali`, login at `tempuser`, do your `usermod`, then delete `tempuser`

Answer (score 1):

Log in as root, then open terminal and run

> **kill -9 -u [old_username] && username -l [old_username] [new_username]**

After that run

> **adduser [new_username] sudo**

to be able to run sudo commands with the new username.

Comment: Man I didnt expect my 2 month old 6 times downvoted question to get answered- thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- Log in as root
- `cat /etc/passwd | grep kali`
- `usermod -l [newusername] [kali]`

Then restart and login with the newusername

Comment: Welcome @katikul !
Take a look on the [FAQ](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) to get tips on how to use the website. This answer could use more polishing to be most useful to others, like formatting, what it suggests that is different from the others and explaining what these commands should be doing. Follow the tips in the FAQ and your answers will become much more relevant and certainly you'll be much better rewarded!